# How to get data from a div in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, controller

I use an input text to put text in div. When I write something in the input and I press the key Enter, the text from the input field is added to a div just below and normally, an array should be updated in my controller with the new value. I don't know how can I get the list of element text added to the div from a controller.

I'm trying to use the property n-change on my div with ng-model but it doesn't work.

```
 <div class="row center" id="searchD" >
    <form id="search" >
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" onchange="createTag($(this).val());"/>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row center" ng-controller="Mainctrl">
    <div id="tagContainer" ng-model="tagList" ng-change="tagList()">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it something like below if that is what you are expecting.

Html :

```
    <div class="row center" id="searchD" ng-controller="Mainctrl">
        <form id="search" >
            <input type="text" id="searchInput" ng-model="tagInput" ng-change="addTag()"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row center">
        <div id="tagContainer" ng-repeat="tag in tagList">{{tag}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Mainctrl:

```
    $scope.tagList = [];

    $scope.addTag = function () {
        $scope.tagList.push($scope.tagInput);
        $scope.tagInput = '';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to get data from the controller onto the html page? If so, you just use angular interpolation `{{ someData }}`

```
<div id="tagContainer" ng-model="tagList" ng-change="tagList()">
  {{ tagList }}
</div>
```

Comment: In addition, if the data is an array you can also iterate over the array using the ngRepeat directive. ng-repeat="tag in tagList" and access each tag with {{ tag }}